# How flush file in perl under mac?

Tags: perl, macos, perl5.10

I have `perl, v5.10.0 built for darwin-thread-multi-2level` in remote iMac. And I want to run some perl script which prints to file some data and flushes after each line of output.

1. $file_handle->flush();
2. autoflush $file_handle;

I have tried this two versions with `use IO::Handle;` in top of the file, but the result I'm getting is `Can't locate object method "autoflush" via package "FileHandle"`.

Comment: did you mean $file_handle->autoflush(); ? Or maybe you should give that a try. Just for grins, I would pass an explicit argument of 1 even though it's supposed to default to true when called...

Answer (score 3):

Where are you getting your `$file_handle` from?  Looks like it's a `FileHandle` instance, not an `IO::Handle` object.

You could try

```
use FileHandle;
```

at the top of the script, instead of `IO::Handle`.  Alternatively, change your code so that `$file_handle` is no longer a `FileHandle` instance.

PS: you really shouldn't be running 5.10.0, it's got quite a few bugs.  5.10.1 or anything newer is a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the "use IO::Handle;" doesn't have a typo?

It looks to me like the module hasn't loaded.

Comment: Yes because same code I'm running in 3 different boxes. Mac, Linux, Win

Comment: Can you drop this in the program just before you autoflush and give me the output? `print map {"$_ => $INC{$_}\n"} keys %INC;`

Answer (score 2):

use FileHandle; solved my issue. I was having issues with Net::SCP::Expect. This happened under CentOS 6.3.

I was getting errors like:
-can't locate object method autoflush via package filehandle
-can't locate object method blocking via package filehandle